# Absolute URL and relative URL

Tags: url, absolute-path

Here's the homepage of Stony Brook University: http://www.stonybrook.edu/

There's a link whose anchor text is "Academics" on the homepage. By checking the source code of the page, I find that the "Academics" link has a relative URL: `academics.shtml`.

To my surprise, the absolute URL: http://www.stonybrook.edu/academics.shtml isn't that of the "Academics" link. In fact, it does not exist at all. The correct absolute URL for the "Academics" link is: http://www.stonybrook.edu/sb/academics.shtml

I'm confused where the path `/sb/` comes from. I'm asking about it because I'm trying to obtain the absolute URL based on the base URL and relative URL using the Java URL class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Also from the source:

```
<base href="http://www.stonybrook.edu/sb/" />
```

Comment: Any suggestion how to get the real base since I only have the one without `/sb/`?

Comment: @TerryLi: Sorry, I'm not sure what you're asking.  AFAIK, the `<base>` tag means that all subsequent relative URLs are relative to it.  That's all.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this by using following markup

```
<base href="http://www.stonybrook.edu/sb/" />
```

Additionally if you need further information regarding absolute vs relative i have found good page with example .
https://downloadgenerators.com/question/what-is-the-major-difference-between-absolute-url-and-relative-url
I hope this will help you.